# Render React Component just by referencing it with its name (in pure HTML code) without ReactDOM.render (Browser-side)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is it possible to render React component's element just by referencing it with its name inline with normal pure HTML code (not JSX)?

Let's say I have this pure html code:

***Code Snippet 1***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
…
</head>

<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to embed my custom tags "or elements" (that refer to some existing React component called "TransportationIcon").

So I want to be able to write tag `<TransportationIcon type='car' />` like below inline with my pure html code, and these tags then get rendered automatically without needing to write `ReactDOM.render(element, containerNode)`:

***Code Snippet 2***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p><TransportationIcon type="car" />This is a paragraph.</p>
<p><TransportationIcon type="bicycle" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><TransportationIcon type="car" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><TransportationIcon type="train" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><TransportationIcon type="bicycle" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><TransportationIcon type="train" /> This is another paragraph.</p>

<script type="text/babel">
  class TransportationIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
      var url = '';
      var name = '';
      switch (this.props.type) {
        case 'car':
          url = 'https://i.imgur.com/RwqSLHj.png';
          name = 'car';
          break;
        case 'train':
          url = 'https://i.imgur.com/ZU470WC.png';
          name = 'train';
          break;
        case 'bicycle':
          url = 'https://i.imgur.com/TmffaDj.png';
          name = 'bicycle';
          break;
        default:
          name = 'no';
      }
      return <span>(<img src={url} style={{height: 1 + 'em'}} /> {name}_icon_here ) </span>;
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try the above code, React doesn't render this at all however I defined my component correctly. I think this is because React doesn't parse pure HTML.

I know that I can tell React to render my `<TransportationIcon … />` tags by adding container elements and then target them using `ReactDOM.render(element, containerNode)` like below:.

***Code Snippet 3***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p><span class="car-icon-container"></span>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p><span class="bicycle-icon-container"></span> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><span class="car-icon-container"></span> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><span class="train-icon-container"></span> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><span class="bicycle-icon-container"></span> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><span class="train-icon-container"></span> This is another paragraph.</p>

<script type="text/babel">
  class TransportationIcon extends React.Component {
    render() {
      var url = '';
      var name = '';
      switch (this.props.type) {
        case 'car':
          url = 'https://i.imgur.com/RwqSLHj.png';
          name = 'car';
          break;
        case 'train':
          url = 'https://i.imgur.com/ZU470WC.png';
          name = 'train';
          break;
        case 'bicycle':
          url = 'https://i.imgur.com/TmffaDj.png';
          name = 'bicycle';
          break;
        default:
          name = 'no';
      }
      return <span>(<img src={url} style={{height: 1 + 'em'}} /> {name}_icon_here ) </span>;
    }
  }

  // Code telling React to render by targetting containers
    var car_icon_containers = document.querySelectorAll('.car-icon-container');
    var train_icon_containers = document.querySelectorAll('.train-icon-container');
    var bicycle_icon_containers = document.querySelectorAll('.bicycle-icon-container');

    [].forEach.call(car_icon_containers, function (car_icon_container) {
            ReactDOM.render(<TransportationIcon type='car' />,
                car_icon_container);
    });

    [].forEach.call(train_icon_containers, function (train_icon_container) {
            ReactDOM.render(<TransportationIcon type='train' />,
                train_icon_container);
    });

    [].forEach.call(bicycle_icon_containers, function (bicycle_icon_container) {
            ReactDOM.render(<TransportationIcon type='bicycle' />,
                bicycle_icon_container);
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However ***Code Snippet 3*** works, I find it exhaustive because for each **component**, I need to write separate container elements (within my pure html code) to be targeted by the `ReactDOM.render()` and also I need to write the `ReactDOM.render()` code itself.

What I'm looking for is some solution in order **not to use** container elements (within my pure html code) at all and write tags themselves directly (that reference to my component) within my pure html code, and get them rendered automatically without needing to write exhaustive unnecessary `ReacDOM.render()` code (like in ***Code Snippet 3***).

I need to get ***Code Snippet 2*** working without writing that much code in ***Code Snippet 3***).

---

There's another somehow similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558300/how-to-render-react-component-without-reactdom-render-function) to mine, but it's asking about server-side rendering, my question is asking about web browser rendering.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is **not possible** to render React components / elements just by referencing it with its name in pure HTML code.

You need to understand:
The notation in your example `<TransportationIcon ... />` **is not HTML**, it is (meant to be) JSX, which is javascript behind the scenes. So you can not insert it into HTML.

As you see in your *Code Snippet 3* the `<TransportationIcon ... />` parts only work inside of `<script>` sections.

#### Example

Consider this example *myTestFile.js*:

```
const myReactElement = <TransportationIcon type="car" />;
```

To make it work, it has to be transpiled with babel:

```
babel myTestFile.js --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

And the result will be:

```
var myReactElement = React.createElement( TransportationIcon, { type: "car" } );
```

And, of course, you can not write something like this in HTML:

```
<body>
<p>React.createElement( TransportationIcon, { type: "car" } );This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

#### Workarounds

So you can not insert javascript directly into HTML. You have to "inject" the javascript into the HTML when the HTML is ready loaded, right as you have done it in your *Code Snippet 3*.

I have a suggestion to shorten it a bit (but it only works if custom tags and attributes are allowed, e.g. not forbidden by the linter):

```
<p><rr @="TransportationIcon" type="car"></rr>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p><rr @="TransportationIcon" type="bicycle"></rr> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><rr @="SomeOtherComponent" type="car"></rr> This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><rr @="SomeOtherComponent" type="train"></rr> This is another paragraph.</p>

...

<script>
    const reactElementsContainer = {
        TransportationIcon,
        SomeOtherComponent
    };
    var react_component_placeholders = document.getElementsByTagName('rr');

    [].forEach.call(react_component_placeholders, function (react_placeholder) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(
                reactElementsContainer[ react_placeholder.getAttribute('@') ],
                { type: react_placeholder.getAttribute('type') }
            ),
            react_placeholder
        );
    });
</script>
```

#### the "React-way"

However, this is not how React is meant to be used. Instead, you should basically write everything in React (and JSX), like this:

```
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script>
    const TransportationIcon = ()=>{
        return React.createElement( 'div', null, 'testdiv' );
    };

    const App = ()=>{
        return (<div>
            <p><TransportationIcon type="car" />This is a paragraph.</p>
            <p><TransportationIcon type="bicycle" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
            <p><TransportationIcon type="car" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
            <p><TransportationIcon type="train" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
            <p><TransportationIcon type="bicycle" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
            <p><TransportationIcon type="train" /> This is another paragraph.</p>
        </div>);
    };

    var appContainer = document.querySelectorAll('#app')[0];

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement( App ),
        appContainer
    );
</script>
</body>
```

This has to go through babel to work. Remember, it should be javascript.

In that way you can have the syntax that you want. But note that there is no *real* HTML anymore, even the `<div>` and `<p>` tags are JSX now.

That also means the website would show an empty page if javascript is disabled / blocked.

#### "parse HTML"

> I think this is because React doesn't parse pure HTML

Almost right: React doen't parse *any* HTML, React is pure javascript.